# Help finding a proof of an identity $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\binom{j}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Help finding a proof of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\binom{j}{k}=(-1)^{n}\binom{j-1}{n}$

I know it's easy to sum up the left side of the identity when the upper limit  is $j$ or $j-1$.

However I have no idea when I need to sum up to an arbitrary limit $n$.

Comment: I think you can look at the expansion for $(1-x)^j$

Comment: OP wants a combinatorial argument, not an algebraic one. (Even if it is the simpler one.)

Comment: I have tried using induction method and $\binom{j}{n}=\binom{j-1}{n-1}+\binom{j-1}{n}$，but I wonder whether there exists a more straight way to solve it.Induction feels like reverse engineering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want a combinatorial proof, see Identity 168 in *Proofs That Really Count*, where the proof uses an almost one-to-one correspondence between even and odd subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ via a mapping that either adds to or removes element $n$ from the subset.

---

For a generating function proof, it is convenient to reverse the order of summation to obtain the equivalent identity $$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{j}{n-k} = \binom{j-1}{n} \tag1$$
Now
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{j}{n-k} z^n
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-z)^k \sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{j}{n-k} z^{n-k} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-z)^k \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{j}{n} z^n \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-z)^k (1+z)^j \\
&=\frac{1}{1+z} (1+z)^j \\
&=(1+z)^{j-1} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{j-1}{n} z^n,
\end{align}
which immediately implies $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you for very cool approaches to the problem!

Comment: Glad to help. One nice thing about the second approach (“snake oil”) is that you don’t need to know the RHS ahead of time.